# Principal symbol of a non-local operator and Atiyah–Singer index formula

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

I am trying to understand the Atiyah–Singer index formula for pseudo-differential operators. As far as I understood, the Fredholm index of the operator $A$ on a manifold can be computed just from the knowledge of its associated principal symbol $\sigma_p(A)$, at least for elliptic operators. However, I am interested in non-local operator of the form
$$
A(f)(x)= \int_{\mathbb R}  \tilde A(x-x') f(x')\,\mathrm d x'
$$
with $f$ in the Schwartz space.

This kind of operators find application in Phisics as they describe non-local responses of materials.

Suppose $B$ acts on $\mathcal C^{\infty}(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ as:
$$
B(f)(x)= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-(x-x')^2/2} f(x')\,\mathrm d x'
$$
and has symbol
$$
\sigma(B)(x,\xi) = e^{-\xi^2/2},\quad(x,\xi)\in\mathbb R^2
$$
(notice, no dependence on $x$).

$\sigma(B)$ is a Hörmander symbol in the class $\mathcal S^{m}_{1,0}$, $\forall\, m\in \mathbb R$.

**Question**: Does $\sigma_p(B)$ exist? Is it a generic feature of non-local operator not to have a principal symbol? Can the Atiyah–Singer index formula be applied to such operators?

N.B. For the notion of Hörmander symbol one can look at the Wikipedia page on [pseudo-differential operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-differential_operator).

Comment: The Wikipedia page refers to Hörmander, and uses the word 'symbol' in the [discussion of linear differential operators with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-differential_operator#Linear_differential_operators_with_constant_coefficients), but seems never explicitly to mention "Hörmander symbol".

Comment: You are right. By "Hörmander symbol" I mean that the symbol is "in the class $S_{1,0}^m$ of Hörmander", using the wording of Wikipedia. I hope there is no big ambiguity in this definition.

Comment: To make classical index theory work it isn't strictly necessary that the operators are _local_, just _pseudolocal_ - meaning they should commute with multiplication by a continuous function modulo compact operators.  It doesn't look like this quite holds for the operators that you introduced, which makes me wonder if these operator are even Fredholm - do you know one way or the other?

Comment: If they aren't Fredholm, then one typical way to proceed is to study the algebra generated by the commutators of your preferred class of operators with multiplication operators by continuous functions - your operators will have a Fredholm-like index in the K-theory of this algebra, and often the right way to generalize the Atiyah-Singer index theorem is to calculate this K-theory group.

Comment: I didn't know about the need to be pseudolocal to work out a classical index theory. Do you have any reference (book&chapter or article) about the topic? And also, would you agree with me that these operators (at least the one in the example) don't have any principal symbol?

Comment: The approach I'm referring to is explained in detail in chapter 10 of Higson and Roe's Analytic K-homology, culminating in theorem 10.6.5.  This shows how to construct a K-homology class from an elliptic operator, and the key point is pseudolocality (for operators constructed via the functional calculus).  I don't think this theory applies directly to your operator, but if you can imitate the analysis to produce a class in some sort of K-homology group then you should get an index theorem as a byproduct.

Comment: (And indeed, it doesn't look to me like the Fourier transform of your operator is a polynomial, but nevertheless it looks like you ought to be able to construct a reasonable functional calculus for the operator.  I still can't tell if it's Fredholm in the traditional sense, though.)